# Count number of checkboxes checked in a table column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am now struggling with counting number of checkboxes checked in a column.
I am trying to count them and display a total at the bottom.
My html is as follows. There are alot more columns!

```
<tr>
    <th>Public Safety</th>
    <td><div class="text-center"><label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" class="chkRootCauseSummary" /> </label></div></td>
    <td><div class="text-center"><label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" class="chkRootCauseSummary" /> </label></div></td>
    <td><div class="text-center"><label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" class="chkRootCauseSummary" /> </label></div></td>
    <td><div class="text-center"><label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" class="chkRootCauseSummary" /> </label></div></td>
    <td><div class="text-center"><label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" class="chkRootCauseSummary" /> </label></div></td>
    <td><div class="text-center"><label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" class="chkRootCauseSummary" /> </label></div></td>
    <td><div class="text-center"><label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" class="chkRootCauseSummary" /> </label></div></td>
    <td><div class="text-center"><label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" class="chkRootCauseSummary" /> </label></div></td>
    <td><div class="text-center"><label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" class="chkRootCauseSummary" /> </label></div></td>
    <td><div class="text-center"><label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" class="chkRootCauseSummary" /> </label></div></td>
    <td><div class="text-center"><label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" class="chkRootCauseSummary" /> </label></div></td>
    <td><div class="text-center"><label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" class="chkRootCauseSummary" /> </label></div></td>
    <td><div class="text-center"><label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" class="chkRootCauseSummary" /> </label></div></td>
    <td><div class="text-center"><label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" class="chkRootCauseSummary" /> </label></div></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>SSW/MS</th>
    <td><div class="text-center"><label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" class="chkRootCauseSummary" /> </label></div></td>
    <td><div class="text-center"><label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" class="chkRootCauseSummary" /> </label></div></td>
    <td><div class="text-center"><label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" class="chkRootCauseSummary" /> </label></div></td>
    <td><div class="text-center"><label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" class="chkRootCauseSummary" /> </label></div></td>
    <td><div class="text-center"><label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" class="chkRootCauseSummary" /> </label></div></td>
    <td><div class="text-center"><label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" class="chkRootCauseSummary" /> </label></div></td>
    <td><div class="text-center"><label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" class="chkRootCauseSummary" /> </label></div></td>
    <td><div class="text-center"><label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" class="chkRootCauseSummary" /> </label></div></td>
    <td><div class="text-center"><label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" class="chkRootCauseSummary" /> </label></div></td>
    <td><div class="text-center"><label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" class="chkRootCauseSummary" /> </label></div></td>
    <td><div class="text-center"><label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" class="chkRootCauseSummary" /> </label></div></td>
    <td><div class="text-center"><label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" class="chkRootCauseSummary" /> </label></div></td>
    <td><div class="text-center"><label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" class="chkRootCauseSummary" /> </label></div></td>
    <td><div class="text-center"><label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" class="chkRootCauseSummary" /> </label></div></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

And my jquery so far:

```
$('#tblRootCauseBody').on('change', 'input[type=checkbox]', function () {
    $(" #tblRootCauseBody tr:not(:last-child) td:nth-child("+ (that.closest('td').index() - 1) + ")").each(function () {
        $(this).html();
    });
});
```

Comment: Hello, Wouldn't that get me all the checkboxes which are checkedon the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the index of `:nth-child()`(index starts from 1), you need to add 1 to the value of `.index()`(starts from 0)

```js
$('#tblRootCauseBody').on('change', 'input[type=checkbox]', function() {
  var index = $(this).closest('td').index() + 1,
    $checked = $(" #tblRootCauseBody tr:not(:last-child) td:nth-child(" + (index) + ") input:checked");
  $('#tblRootCauseBody tr:last-child > :nth-child(' + index + ')').text($checked.length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody id="tblRootCauseBody">
    <tr>
      <th>Public Safety</th>
      <td>
        <div class="text-center">
          <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" class="chkRootCauseSummary" />
          </label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="text-center">
          <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" class="chkRootCauseSummary" />
          </label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="text-center">
          <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" class="chkRootCauseSummary" />
          </label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="text-center">
          <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" class="chkRootCauseSummary" />
          </label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="text-center">
          <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" class="chkRootCauseSummary" />
          </label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="text-center">
          <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" class="chkRootCauseSummary" />
          </label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="text-center">
          <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" class="chkRootCauseSummary" />
          </label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="text-center">
          <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" class="chkRootCauseSummary" />
          </label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="text-center">
          <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" class="chkRootCauseSummary" />
          </label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="text-center">
          <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" class="chkRootCauseSummary" />
          </label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="text-center">
          <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" class="chkRootCauseSummary" />
          </label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="text-center">
          <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" class="chkRootCauseSummary" />
          </label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="text-center">
          <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" class="chkRootCauseSummary" />
          </label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="text-center">
          <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" class="chkRootCauseSummary" />
          </label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>SSW/MS</th>
      <td>
        <div class="text-center">
          <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" class="chkRootCauseSummary" />
          </label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="text-center">
          <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" class="chkRootCauseSummary" />
          </label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="text-center">
          <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" class="chkRootCauseSummary" />
          </label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="text-center">
          <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" class="chkRootCauseSummary" />
          </label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="text-center">
          <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" class="chkRootCauseSummary" />
          </label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="text-center">
          <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" class="chkRootCauseSummary" />
          </label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="text-center">
          <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" class="chkRootCauseSummary" />
          </label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="text-center">
          <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" class="chkRootCauseSummary" />
          </label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="text-center">
          <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" class="chkRootCauseSummary" />
          </label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="text-center">
          <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" class="chkRootCauseSummary" />
          </label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="text-center">
          <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" class="chkRootCauseSummary" />
          </label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="text-center">
          <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" class="chkRootCauseSummary" />
          </label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="text-center">
          <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" class="chkRootCauseSummary" />
          </label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="text-center">
          <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" class="chkRootCauseSummary" />
          </label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: There is a chance that OP was confused about rows and columns. He have provided an extra black `td` to the end of each row.

Comment: Nope, im not confused :D That is for total checkboxes checked in a row :)