# How to properly count checked checkboxes of html table column using element's class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, razor

I am trying to fetch the count of checked checkboxes from the HTML table column in a razor page using jQuery actually. I am not collecting ids of the checkboxes instead trying to use class to maintain the count. However, when I click on the checkbox the count initiates with : 2 x number of total table rows + checked checkboxes. It that a .css file issue? I am loading my checkbox column(appended) using a model in the mvc project.

**Here's my script:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {


        $(".tblChkBx").change(function () {
            $("#lblCountRecords").text($(".tblChkBx").filter(":checked").length);
        });

}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <table id="data"
           class="table table-striped table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr id="thead"
                class="reviewsubhead">

                <th>guest name</th>
                <th>
                    <div class="form-control" onclick="clearRadio()" font-size:8px;">
                        <a id="btnClear" class="arrow-link" onclick="clearRadio()" style="font-size: 0.77em;">
                            clear: <label id="lblCountRecords">0</label>/<label id="lblTotalCount">0</label>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tbody">
            @for (int guestNum = 0; guestNum < Model.GuestUserList.Count; guestNum++)
            {
                <tr>

                    <td>@Model.GuestUserList[guestNum].Name</td>
                    <td align="center">
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(c => c.GuestUserList[guestNum].ChkBox, new { @class = "tblChkBx" })
                        @Html.HiddenFor(c => c.GuestUserList[guestNum].Req_id)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

[image]

Any ideas what's going wrong?

Comment: I think this older question might have a good answer that is helpful to you too - seems to be doing essentially the same thing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35893085/count-number-of-checkboxes-checked-in-a-table-column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, but I think your selector is wrong.  I don't know anything about razor, but assuming it's rendering to standard html, then it should be rendering <input type=checkbox>'s

A selector that will work is this:

```
console.log($("input[type='checkbox']:checked").length)
```